# Julia Doubly Linked List

Tags: gratis, library, julia

[Julia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Julia_%28programming_language%29) has few [Data structures in the Core library.](http://julia.readthedocs.org/en/latest/stdlib/collections/)

The [Data Structures library](https://github.com/JuliaLang/DataStructures.jl) adds many.
But to my knowledge does not add a doubly linked list.

I want a doubly linked list so that I can have fast insertion into the middle of the list.
Does a well-known julia library exist that contains a doubly linked list?